fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Kaneva134/Display-flex.git/' not found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Kaneva134/Display-flex.git/' not found
When I try to clone a repository I received the above error message. How to solve it?
I was trying to create a repository and clone it. I signed in github.com and I ha access to internet. I created a new repository and copied the Url to paste it in gitbash.
